# how to split one string into multiple rows (by every eight chracter)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, google-spreadsheets

i have some data below, could there be anyway to split this all string data into multiple rows, each row with 8 characters. Appreciates ur help. ^^"

**Raw data:**
00002040A69BC43B0AD7A33C6666E63F6F12033B0AD7A33C9A99993F6F12033B0AD7A33C333333406F12833A0AD7A33C666606406F12033A0AD7A33C3333B33F6F12033A0AD7A33C6666A64017B751390AD7A33C6666064017B7D1380AD7A33C3333B33F17B751390AD7A33CCDCCCC3FA69BC43B0AD7A33C00002040A69BC43B0AD7A33C6666E63F52499D3B0AD7A33C666606406F12833A0AD7A33C6666264017B7513A0AD7A33C6666064017B7D1380AD7A33C3333734052499D390AD7A33C0000A04017B751390AD7A33C6666064017B7D1380AD7A33C

**Output should be like:**

00002040

A69BC43B

0AD7A33C

6666E63F

6F12033B0AD7A33C9A99993F6F12033B0AD7A33C333333406F12833A0AD7A33C666606406F12033A0AD7A33C3333B33F6F12033A0AD7A33C6666A64017B751390AD7A33C6666064017B7D1380AD7A33C3333B33F17B751390AD7A33CCDCCCC3FA69BC43B0AD7A33C00002040A69BC43B0AD7A33C6666E63F52499D3B0AD7A33C666606406F12833A0AD7A33C6666264017B7513A0AD7A33C6666064017B7D1380AD7A33C3333734052499D390AD7A33C0000A04017B751390AD7A33C6666064017B7D1380AD7A33C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Find what: `(.{8})`
3. Replace with: `\1\n`
4. Select `Wrap around`
5. Search mode: `Regular expression`
6. Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>